# Transform parse tree into XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, tree, antlr4

I have a compiled grammar and I want to use it to transform an input sequence into an XML. Please note that in my case I have a very large grammar with many rules and I would like to avoid overriding each grammar rule in my code.

I will use an example to avoid confusion. Let us have a following **grammar**

```
grammar expr;

prog: stat+ ;

stat: expr NEWLINE
 | ID '=' expr NEWLINE
 | NEWLINE
;

expr:  expr ('*'|'/') expr
 | INT
 | ID
 | '(' expr ')'
;

ID : [a-zA-Z]+ ; // match identifiers
INT : [0-9]+ ; // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ; // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

**Input sequence**

```
A = 10
B = A * A
```

**Expected output**

```
<prog> 
    <stat> 
        A = 
        <expr> 10
        </expr> 
        \r\n
    </stat>  
    <stat> 
        B = 
        <expr>
            <expr>A</expr> 
            * 
            <expr> A</expr>
        </expr> 
        \r\n
    </stat>
</prog>
```

which corresponds to a parse tree

[image]

Currently I use an approach where I create a `ParseTree` and using the `toStringTree` method I generate the following string

```
(prog (stat A = (expr 10) \r\n) (stat B = (expr (expr A) * (expr A)) \r\n))
```

which I subsequently transform into the XML shown above (I use simple generic code working for any grammar). I find this approach dummy. Is it possible to solve it without `toStringTree`? I would like to avoid the need to override each grammar rule in my Visitor. (I have hundreds of them).

**EDIT**

I basically need some kind of generic ParseTree serialization into the XML format. The major goal is that I will not have to write special serialization method in Java for each rule.

Comment: How about printing doing a recursive descent on ParseTree using a static method ``printXml(ParseTree tree) ``?

Comment: @StefanHaustein I will check it, thanks. I do not have much experience with Antlr.

Comment: Producing XML isn't really a good idea.   How will you manipulate it?  XSLT isn't really very good on large trees, and you'll get huge trees for modest size Java programs.  Worse, XSLT isn't good at context-sensitive checking and all java constructs are context sensitives (variables mean different things depending on their declaration).  See Life After Parsing for why you want more than just the AST anyway: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Comment: @IraBaxter My trees will be of small size (tens to hundreds of elements) and I plan to use an XQuery engine for searching and manipulation.

Comment: @RadimBača: OK, small trees ... maybe XML by itself won't drown you.  But serious manipulation of those trees according to the context-sensitive nature of the language... XQuery won't work out well.  Read the bit about life after parsing.

Comment: @IraBaxter It would be nice to mention that you work for the company whose product your link mentions as the superior alternative.

Comment: @rubystallion:  Well, the link is intended to inform people about the issues of parsing.  Yes, that page also discusses "our" product because a) it addresses those issues and b) shows *how* those issues can be addressed effectively.  Any good solution (OP is chasing a bad one with XML) will have to address those issues.   (In fact, the product mentioned was built by myself personally with my own funds with help from a few others).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this approach might suit your needs. I wrapped terminal symbols with extra tag `t` for readability, also skipping those with white-space. Yet it should not be a big problem to adjust the output if required.

```
final exprLexer lexer = new exprLexer(CharStreams.fromString("A=10\nB = A * A\n"));
final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
final exprParser parser = new exprParser(tokens);
final ParseTree tree = parser.prog();
ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new exprBaseListener()
{
    final String INDENT = "    ";
    int level = 0;
    @Override
    public void enterEveryRule(final ParserRuleContext ctx)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s<%s>%n", indent(), parser.getRuleNames()[ctx.getRuleIndex()]);
        ++level;
        super.enterEveryRule(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitEveryRule(final ParserRuleContext ctx)
    {
        --level;
        System.out.printf("%s</%s>%n", indent(), parser.getRuleNames()[ctx.getRuleIndex()]);
        super.exitEveryRule(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitTerminal(final TerminalNode node)
    {
        final String value = node.getText();
        if (!value.matches("\\s+"))
        {
            System.out.printf("%s<t>%s</t>%n", indent(), node.getText());
        }
        super.visitTerminal(node);
    }

    private String indent()
    {
        return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(level, INDENT));
    }
}, tree);
```

Comment: Excellent, I new that there is a better solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilise ANTLR4's visitor functionality. Depending on the tool you're using, you might need to add the [`-visitor` command line parameter](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md) during the generating of the classes.

For this to work nicely, I added some [labels to your parser rules](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels):

```antlr
prog
 : stat+ EOF
 ;

stat
 : expr NEWLINE        #exprStat
 | ID '=' expr NEWLINE #assignStat
 | NEWLINE             #emptyStat
 ;

expr
 : lhs=expr op=('*'|'/') rhs=expr #multExpr
 | INT                            #intExpr
 | ID                             #idExpr
 | '(' expr ')'                   #nestedExpr
 ;
```

Your visitor could look like this:

```java
public class XmlVisitor extends exprBaseVisitor<String> {

  @Override
  public String visitProg(exprParser.ProgContext ctx) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<prog>");
    for (exprParser.StatContext stat : ctx.stat()) {
      builder.append(super.visit(stat));
    }
    return builder.append("</prog>").toString();
  }

  @Override
  public String visitExprStat(exprParser.ExprStatContext ctx) {
    return "expr";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitAssignStat(exprParser.AssignStatContext ctx) {
    return "<stat>" + ctx.ID() + " = " + super.visit(ctx.expr()) + "\\r\\n</stat>";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitEmptyStat(exprParser.EmptyStatContext ctx) {
    return "\\r\\n";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitMultExpr(exprParser.MultExprContext ctx) {
    return "<expr>" + super.visit(ctx.lhs) + ctx.op.getText() + super.visit(ctx.rhs) + "</expr>";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitIntExpr(exprParser.IntExprContext ctx) {
    return "<expr>" + ctx.INT().getText() + "</expr>";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitIdExpr(exprParser.IdExprContext ctx) {
    return "<expr>" + ctx.ID().getText() + "</expr>";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitNestedExpr(exprParser.NestedExprContext ctx) {
    return "<expr>" + super.visit(ctx.expr()) + "</expr>";
  }
}
```

To test this visitor, run the following code:

```java
String source = "A = 10\nB = A * A\n";
exprLexer lexer = new exprLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
exprParser parser = new exprParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree tree = parser.prog();
String xml = new XmlVisitor().visit(tree);
System.out.println(xml);
```

which will print:

```
<prog><stat>A = <expr>10</expr>\r\n</stat><stat>B = <expr><expr>A</expr>*<expr>A</expr></expr>\r\n</stat></prog>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. However, please note my last sentence "I would like to avoid the need to override each grammar rule in my Visitor. (I have hundreds of them).". Moreover, if something changes in the grammar, the visitor have to be changed appropriately which I find unnecessary in my current solution.

Comment: If one of your grammar rules change, you will always need to change something else. Be it in a visitor, or in a static method you wrote. I think this is the "best" (cleanest) way to solve your problem, that is why I posted it. Feel free to use it or not: I'm sure it will benefit someone. And you're welcome, of course! :)

Comment: A static method where you inspect your tree and emit your nodes will (probably) become a big pile of spaghetti code. In a visitor, each node is emitted in its own method keeping it nice and tidy. Also very easy to unit test!

Comment: I agree with you about the static method. I have a feeling that my parsing of `toStringTree` result is the most simplest and versatile solution for the problem right now. I really do not want to write a visitor for all grammar rules right now (as there can be really large number of them).

Comment: The ANTLR nodes must be tagged so one can tell them apart.  So, to produce XML is rather trivial:  walk the tree, inspect the node, determine its type, produce XML for that root and its (recursive) children.  The fact that ANTLR can print a LISP-like version tells you produce an XML equivalent must be trivial to implement; just steal that code and hack it up.  (We produce XML from our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit this way.  Takes about 50 lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a ANTLR grammar that reads the LISP-style tree produced by `ParseTree.toStringTree` method. Project is accessible [here](https://github.com/RadimBaca/antlr-parse-tree-xml-export). It has the following parts

**Grammar**

```
grammar str;

expr:
 STRING expr                                # exprString
 | LR_BRACKET expr RR_BRACKET expr          # exprParenthesis
 | LR_STRING_BRACKET expr RR_BRACKET expr   # exprRule 
 | <EOF>                                    # exprEnd
 | EOF_MARK                                 # exprEOF
 |                                          # exprEpsilon
;

EOF_MARK:            '<EOF>' ;
LR_STRING_BRACKET:  '(' ~[ ()]+;
LR_BRACKET:         '(';
RR_BRACKET:         ')';
STRING:             ~[ ()]+;
SPACE:              [ \t\r\n]+    -> skip; // toss out whitespace
```

**strXMLVisitor.java**

```
public class strXMLVisitor extends strBaseVisitor<String> {

  @Override
  public String visitExprString(strParser.ExprStringContext ctx) 
  {
    return ctx.STRING().getText() + super.visit(ctx.expr());
  }

  @Override
  public String visitExprParenthesis(strParser.ExprParenthesisContext ctx) {
    return "(" + super.visit(ctx.expr(0)) + ")" + super.visit(ctx.expr(1));
  }

  @Override
  public String visitExprRule(strParser.ExprRuleContext ctx) {
    String value = ctx.LR_STRING_BRACKET().getText().substring(1);
    return "<" + value + ">" + super.visit(ctx.expr(0)) + "</" + value + ">" + super.visit(ctx.expr(1));
  }

  @Override
  public String visitExprEnd(strParser.ExprEndContext ctx) {
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitExprEOF(strParser.ExprEOFContext ctx) {
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public String visitExprEpsilon(strParser.ExprEpsilonContext ctx) {
    return "";
  }  
}
```

**main.java**

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // create a CharStream that reads from standard input
       ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
       // create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
       strLexer lexer = new strLexer(input);
       // create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
       CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
       // create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
       strParser parser = new strParser(tokens);
       ParseTree tree = parser.expr(); // begin parsing at init rule

       String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + new strXMLVisitor().visit(tree);
       System.out.println(xml);      
    }
}
```

Once you have antlr4 ready (and reference in the CLASSPATH as well) you may use the following commands to run it:

```
 antlr4 -visitor str.g4
 javac *.java
 java main < file
```

File has to contain an input in the LISP-tree format and the result is XML on the standard output.

Comment: There is a problem with "(" and ")" symbols in file.
If  either one is present, the produced XML is invalid..